# Securing files and folders with htaccess

Tags: security, .htaccess

I have a couple of files on my server that contains sensitive information. Only the server should be allowed to edit these files, no one else should be able to read/access them. They are stored as .txt.

I've stored them in a separate folder, and added a .htaccess file with:

```
<Files *>
Deny from all
</Files>
```

My question is weather it's secure enough to store sensitive information with .htaccess, or if someone can hack it and get access to the files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess is as secure as you can get, on a server-side basis.

All .ht files by default are un-accessible to the public, so no-one can edit or view the .htaccess file unless they access it through FTP ect. So the .htaccess file is secure as your server is.

Comment: Thanks Brad! Does that also include all the files in the same folder as the .htaccess file (if .htaccess contains the text writte in the first post)?